# /etc/sudoers file with permissions set to 640 instead of 0440: what does it mean?

Tags: permissions, debian, sudo

So I'm still new to GNU/Linux: recently I installed Debian 9.1 with KDE. Now after executing:

`stat --format '%a' /etc/sudoers`

I found out that my sudoers file has the `640` permissions instead `0440` set. I changed this by running `pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers` and inspected the file's contents which seem to be fine.

Now I'd like to know what could have caused these permissions to change and how problematic that is. I only read that this is a security risk.
And what does it mean: does that happen often? How to best prevent these permissions from changing? Continous monitoring of the file's permissions with immediate warnings of any change maybe? Is there a tool for this?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the file is owned by root:root, there's no security risk.
And your changes don't even matter.

You specified that root is not allowed to write to the file.

- If not root, who else...?
- root can change the permission back